# iphone: uiscrollview doesn't scroll? but contentsize is set..?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, scroll

hey people,
I have some data and want to show this in a new view inside a navigation-stack.

I created some new viewcontroller class with XIB file. Then I edited the XIB file and placed the following hierachy:

```
1 files owner
2 first responder
3 scrollview
3.1 view
3.1.1 label1
3.1.2 label2
3.1.3 label3
3.1.4 image4
```

I arranged the labels and the image. the content of the labels may differ and they should size dynamically. I also did the IBOutlets in the viewcontroller class and connected everything correctly. the files owner's view delegate is set to view..

then I load the viewcontroller and I do in the "viewDidLoad" - method the following:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

self.currentPageURL.text = [self.offerItem objectForKey: @"page-url"];
self.currentPrice.text = [self.offerItem objectForKey: @"price"];
self.currentRank.text = [self.offerItem objectForKey: @"rank"];
self.currentName.text = [self.offerItem objectForKey: @"name"];
self.currentProducerName.text = [self.offerItem objectForKey: @"producer-name"];

self.currentDescription.text = [self.offerItem objectForKey: @"description"];

self.imageViewForImage.image = [helperClass resizeImage:[self.offerItem objectForKey: @"picture"] forSize:CGSizeMake(280.0, 280.0) ];

[theScrollview setScrollEnabled:YES];
[theScrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 1200)];
[theScrollview flashScrollIndicators];

[theScrollview addSubview:theView];
```

}

when I start the app in my simulator, everything is shown, but if I try to scroll, nothing happens..

what do I do wrong?

Comment: what is the frame size of view `3.1`?

Comment: I set the size to 320x1200 in IB.. the scrollview has also 320x1200 set in IB..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Immediately change the frame of `theScrollView` to 320x480 and you should see scrolling.

Comment: I did this - but the problem stays the same..
scrollview is at 320x480 in IB and the view beneath is at 320x1200..

Comment: So basically you are able to see part of the content but aren't able to scroll? What about 'userInteractionEnabled` property? Is it set to YES?

Comment: yes, it is set in IB and I added additionally [theScrollview setUserInteractionEnabled:YES]; programmatically in the ViewDidLoad-method above - no reaction, no scrolling... is the stack I posted above correct? scrollview has a view as child? scrollview has the dimension of the iphone screen and view the dimension of the whole content?

Comment: Wait a minute? Is `view` at `3.1` referred to by `self.view`?

Comment: THAT's IT, thanks Deepak for you help!!

the problem was that I didn't set the file owners standard view outlet to the scrollview, it was still set to the view 3.1
I put the "view"-standard-outlet to scrollview and now everything works!!
oh man, this took me 5 h to figure this out..
thanks again, Deepak!

Answer (score 20):

Autolayout set some constraints after the view loads, so, pick your code that sets the content size in viewDidLoad and put in viewDidAppear, and your code won't be rewritten.

This worked for me.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
  [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 1000)];
}
```

and sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Worked for me! Instead of using CGSizeMake, you could als calculate the width/height from the content in the scrollview.

Answer (score 11):

Ensure that "Use Autolayout" is **unchecked** in the IB Document attributes. I had the exact same issue, setting the correct contentSize and all, but with this feature enabled, scrolling was always disabled.

[image: Use Autolayout needs to be OFF]

**UPDATE** To use Autolayout, explicitly set the width and height of the scrollView's content in the viewDidAppear method, like this:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    // set the scrollview to the specified size
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(screenRect.size.width, 1100)];

    [scrollView setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenRect.size.width, screenRect.size.height)];

    [scrollView setScrollIndicatorInsets:UIEdgeInsetsFromString(@"{0,0,0,-1.0}")];

}
```

Comment: why this work in this way ? you should declare the content in the viewDidAppear!